# Need help regarding dynamic CSS selector

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, css-selectors

Need help regarding dynamic CSS selector.

I have following CSS selector for my desired web element:

```
#sub-cat-822 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)
```

I need to pass variable (variable name is: ***Added_Main_category_id1***) containing dynamic value only for **cat-822** (within above  CSS selector). Kindly can someone advise how to adjust variable in above CSS selector so that it can run smoothly?

**outer html of desired web element:**

```
<input required="required" id="edited_name" name="sub_cate" value="" placeholder="" class="form-control" type="text">
```

**csspath of desired web element:**

```
html body.nav-md.pace-done.modal-open div.container.body div.main_container div.right_col div.right_col_container div.right_col_wrapper div.x_panel div.x_content div.post-box ul.cat_accordion.list-group li#854.list-group-item.category-list-item-854 div.cat-name div#sub-cat-854.modal.fade.in div.modal-dialog div.modal-content form div.modal-body.clearfix div.edit-photo-poup div.col-xs-8.col-sm-6 input#edited_name.form-control
```

**cssselector of desired web element:**

```
  #sub-cat-822 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)
```

**xpath of desired web element:**

```
//*[@id="edited_name"]
```

Comment: Post your HTML.

Comment: I don't see anything. Push to your question it.

Comment: Ratmir Asanov
can you please share what exactly you require?

Comment: Post your HTML inside question with indentations.

Comment: The desired element has an ID, why aren't you using it? `driver.findElement(By.id("edited_name"));`?

Comment: Your question is confusing. The CSS path and CSS selector don't match at all. Please post a link to the page.

Comment: Dear JeffC,
Sorry i just saw your question and apologize for late reply. In fact when i try to use driver.findElement(By.id("edited_name")); i am getting [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible] error after execution.

Please note that same script gets executed successfully if i pass complete cssselector: i.e. #sub-cat-854 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)

Comment: Actually my script gets successfully executed using following cssselector:

Invoke_Test_Instance.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sub-cat-831 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys("input value");

Only thing is i need to use my variable containing dynamic value for cat-831

Comment: I added an answer based on your comment

Comment: guys can any one help regarding discussed query?

Answer (score 0):

if the id "edited_name" is unique in the HTML sourcecode, just use `#edited_name` as the CSS Selector

Comment: Dear Taran,
Thanks for your response. Infact when i try to run my script using #edited_name in cssselector i am getting: [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible] error after execution whereas same script gets executed successfully if i pass complete cssselector: i.e. 
#sub-cat-854 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)

Comment: only thing is i need to pass variable instead of cat-854 within cssselector because my variable contains dynamic value. and i am using cssselector because i am getting so many different exceptions while using xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the selector string as just a regular string. You can insert any variable, etc. that you want into it.

You said that the below works

```
Invoke_Test_Instance.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sub-cat-831 > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys("input value");
```

You can modify that using a variable like

```
String id = "#sub-cat-831";
Invoke_Test_Instance.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(id + " > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys("input value");
```

and then change the `id` variable to any string you want.

That said... having a CSS selector, or any locator, with that many levels is likely going to be very fragile. Any change in any level of the DOM will break that locator due to the number of levels and also the indexes you are using.

Comment: Dear Jeffc- the issue is with in #sub-cat-831only cat-831 is dynamic for which i want to use variable (i want to use my variable with #sub-  or you can say that #sub-+my variable+ combination is required along with remaining cssselector part which is static) so that my script should be able to run with dybamic cssselector. Hope you understand this.

Answer (score 0):

***Below Logic Successfully worked. Thanks Jeffc for sharing the idea.***

String category_id = Added_Main_category_id1;//variable containing #cat-906 dynamic value

String truncated_category_id;

truncated_category_id =category_id.substring(category_id.lastIndexOf("#")+1);// removing # and getting rest of the dynamic value (i.e. cat-906)

String id = "#sub-"+truncated_category_id;

Thread.sleep(3000);

Invoke_Test_Instance.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(id +"> div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys("Field Input value");  // passing dynamic variable and other static value as cssselector

Answer (score -1):

Is it really necessary that you need to use CSS selector and not Xpath? Normally Xpath helps in dynamic scenarios. See below code

```
String searchText = "text in the webtable";
driver.get("http://some.site.having.webtable/");
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='" + searchText + "']"));
```

You can then customize your xpath according to your needs.

Please post your HTML to make it easier.

Comment: SteroidKing666
Yes i really need cssselector.. because in my scenario i spent lot of time and it's working fine with static cssselector so i need to pass only one of my variable containing dynamic value and remaining cssselector always remain same

Comment: Can you please post the HTML in your original post by editing? Or better yet just provide us the link to check.

Comment: Dear SteroidKing666,
As you advised, I have provided outer html as well as csspath within my question. Looking forward for resolution of my query. Thanks

Comment: XPath is not any more advantageous than CSS selectors when creating dynamic locators. They both work the same except CSS selectors are faster, more widely consistent in their support, and easier syntax to learn.

Comment: @JeffC
Thanks. Can you kindly help resolving my issue. Thanks again

Comment: @Ali I asked two questions in the comments... waiting for your answers.

Comment: @Ali No, not opinion. You can google for yourself and verify these statements. This answer states, `Normally Xpath helps in dynamic scenarios`, and is alleging that XPath is better. My point is that XPath is no better than CSS selectors in dealing with dynamic scenarios... they are exactly the same. CSS selectors have other advantages that I also listed. XPath is very powerful but with that power comes a lot of complexity. CSS selectors can do 95% of what XPath can do... the exceptions are locating an element by contained text and DOM navigation. Those only XPath can do.

Comment: @JeffC, 
Your opinion and analysis is really respectable to me and you are absolutely right. In fact i was intended to say that i need the resolution of my issue using cssselector.